# Enum with vbscript

Tags: vbscript, enums

Since vbscript does not support enumerations, is there any work arround to face this problem?

I have this code:

```
Private Enum dataType
 dt_Nothing
 dt_Boolean
 dt_Decimal
 dt_Double
 dt_Integer
 dt_string
 dt_Array
 dt_NetJSON
End Enum
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8):

Using constants is quite logical. On the other hand you can use a global instance of your own class that mimics VB Enums. Note that, will look just like enums and I'm not sure it is really necessary.

```
Class EnumDataType
    Public  dt_Nothing, dt_Boolean, dt_Decimal
    Private Sub Class_Initialize
        dt_Nothing = 1
        dt_Boolean = 2
        dt_Decimal = 4
    End Sub
End Class

Dim dataType
Set dataType = New EnumDataType

WScript.Echo dataType.dt_Nothing Or dataType.dt_Boolean Or dataType.dt_Decimal
```

Answer (score 7):

According to http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1146844 the best way is by using constants.

```
Const dt_Nothing = Something
Const dt_Boolean = Something
Const dt_Decimal = Something
Const dt_Double = Something
Const dt_Integer = Something
Const dt_string = Something
Const dt_Array = Something
Const dt_NetJSON = Something
```

I couldn't find another way. I will search if there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Another way I sometimes use is declare an dictionary.
Like:

Dim oEnum

set oEnum = CreateObject("scripting.Dictionary")

And on thread/app init I do fill it with the values I like to use likewise I should use the enumeration.

So :

oEnum.Add 0, "Enum1"

oEnum.Add 1, "Enum2"

At the place in code I like to use the enumeration I call this dictionaryobject like:
someval = oEnum.Items()(index) -> the index is kinda like the enumeration method.

Edit: you could use this also like:

oEnum.Add "CONSTANTNAME", integer value

Then you can get the value via:

oEnum.Item(CONSTANTNAME)

Grz John

Answer (score 0):

Just to remind, you can avoid bloat and make it painless by doing (eg) this..

```
Public Const xupv = 1, xvet = 2, xhid = 3, xban = 4, xrep = 5, xech = 6, xvus = 7, xfDpth = 8, xEds = 9
```

Or this..

```
Public Const _
  xupv = 1 _
, xvet = 2 _
, xhid = 3 _
, xban = 4 _
, xrep = 5 _
, xech = 6 _
, xvus = 7 _
, xfDpth = 8 _
, xEds = 9
```

(That's tested. parses fine)

Answer (score -5):

Here are lines of code that I found that worked.

```
Const navOpenInNewTab = &H800
Set IE1=CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE1.Visible=true
IE1.Navigate2 "http://blogs.msdn.com"
IE1.Navigate2 "http://blogs.msdn.com/tonyschr", CLng(navOpenInNewTab)
IE1.Navigate2 "http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing", CLng(navOpenInNewTab)
IE1.Navigate2 "http://msdn.microsoft.com", CLng(navOpenInNewTab)
```

'Don't forget to close IE using the line of code below:
    IE1.Quit